# How do I use Routes instead of Switch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm quite new to routing and following a tutorial but can't seem to get things to work.

This is the tutorial I'm follwing (26:45 - 29:00): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntYXj9W1Ez8&t=1720s

I have a file with:

```
const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route
                path='/:category/search/:keyword'
                component={Catalog}
            />
            <Route
                path='/:category/:id'
                component={Detail}
            />
            <Route
                path='/:category'
                component={Catalog}
            />
            <Route
                path='/'
                exact
                component={Home}
            />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

And my App.js:

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Route
        render={(props) => (
          <>
            <Header {...props} />
            <Routes />
            <Footer />
          </>
        )}
      />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

It's supposed to render out the texts: Header, Home, Footer, but nothing gets rendered out.

I did some searching and found out that Switch has been replaced with Routes. So I changed the import and Switch tags to Routes but it's still not working.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: Tried reading the react router docs, including the migrate v5 to v6 which replaces Switch with Routes, but still can't get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

In your `index.js` or `main.js`

```
import App from './App';
...
<BrowserRouter>
   <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

and in your `App.js`

```
return (
<>
 <Header/>
 <Routes>
   <Route path='/' element={<Home />}></Route>
   <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />}></Route>
   <Route path='/category/:id' element={<Category/>}></Route>
 </Routes>
 <Footer />
</>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a new way of routing with react-router-dom v6.4:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: (
      <div className="home">
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          ...etc
        </div>
        <main className="main">...</main>
      </div>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: '/:category/search/:keyword',
    element: <Catalog />,
  },
  {
    path: '/:category/:id',
    element: <Detail />,
  },
  {
    path: '/:category',
    element: <Catalog />,
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />,
  },
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router}>
    <App />
  </RouterProvider>
);
```